# Prove that $\mathcal{B} = \{g_{1},g_{2},g_{3}\}$ is a basis for $V$ and obtain the coordinates of $f = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2$ in this ordered basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be a (real) vector space of all polynomials functions from $\textbf{R}$ to $\textbf{R}$ of degree at most two, that is, the space of all functions of the form 
\begin{align*}
f(x) = c_{0} + c_{1}x + c_{2}x^{2}
\end{align*}
Let $t$ be a fixed real number and define
\begin{align*}
g_{1}(x) = 1,\quad g_{2}(x) = x + t,\quad g_{3}(x) = (x+t)^{2} = x^{2} + 2xt + t^{2}
\end{align*}
Prove that $\mathcal{B} = \{g_{1},g_{2},g_{3}\}$ is a basis for $V$. If $f(x) = c_{0} + c_{1}x + c_{2}x^{2}$, what are the coordinates of $f$ in this ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

At first, we must prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is linear independent. Indeed, this is the case when $t\neq 0$, because
\begin{align*}
& ag_{1} + bg_{2} + cg_{3} = a + b(x + t) + c(x^{2} + 2xt + t^{2}) = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& (a + bt + ct^{2}) + (b + 2ct)x + cx^{2} = 0 \Longrightarrow c = b = a = 0
\end{align*}
The same applies to $t = 0$. Consequently, the coordinates of $f$ in $\mathcal{B}$ are given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
c'_{0} \\
c'_{1} \\
c'_{2}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t & t^{2}\\
0 & 1 & 2t\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{0} \\
c_{1} \\
c_{2}
\end{bmatrix} = \ldots
\end{align*}

Could someone double-check my solution?

Comment: Looks good to me. Just finish the last equation

Comment: Polynomials of degree $2$ do not form a vector space. You should define $V$ as the space of all polynomials of degree at most $2$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was a typo.